# Unable to call methods from onPostExecute

Tags: java, android

I am using the an asynchronous task to run a JSON downloader as thus: (abridged)

```
public class JSONDownloader extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        if(JSONstate == false){
            try {
                final URL url = new URL([REDACTED]);

                final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                urlConnection.connect();
                final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    sb.append((char) inputStream.read());
                }
                String result = sb.toString();

                JSONObject jsonOrg = new JSONObject(result);

                String ok = "ok";

                Response = jsonOrg.getString("response");
                System.out.println(Response);

                if(Response.equals(ok)){
                    Settingsresponse = true;

                    orgName = jsonOrg.getString("orgName");
                    System.out.println("orgName" + orgName);
                    accessPointName = jsonOrg.getString("attendanceRecorderName");
                    System.out.println("accessPointName" + accessPointName);
                    lat = jsonOrg.getString("latitude");
                    System.out.println("lat" + lat);
                    longi = jsonOrg.getString("longitude");
                    System.out.println("longi" + longi);
                    floor = jsonOrg.getString("floor");
                    System.out.println("floor" + floor);
                    orgId = jsonOrg.getString("orgId");
                    System.out.println("orgId" + orgId);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Data sent was erroneous");
                    Settingsresponse = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.print(e);      
            }
        }
        else if(JSONstate == true){
            try {                   
                                    [redacted]
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Data sent was erroneous");
                    Settingsresponse = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.print(e);      
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        if(JSONstate == false){
            System.out.println("This piece of code is definitely being run");
            setfields();
        }
        else if(JSONstate == true){
            settestfields();
        //This method does not run upon the completion of the JSON request, as it supposedly should
                    }
    }
}
```

Once the JSONRequest has been completed, the 'onPostExecute' method doesn't run. I have been attempting to use this method so that a set of fields can be updated as soon as the request is complete, instead of having to set a definite wait time. Am I simply utilizing the code wrong? Or is there something I've missed?

Comment: how do you start your async task? You have to call `myAsyncTask.execute();` and not `myAsyncTask.doInBackGround()`or something similar. And by the way instead of using the `JSONstate` variable, you can just add a `RETURN TYPE BOOLEAN` and ask for the result in the  `onPostExecute`. You should look again into  the TYPES it's not a good practice to use `OBJECT` as all types!

Comment: Is JSONstate not out of scope for onPostExecute()?

Comment: The AsynTask is called with a '.execute'.

I don't understand what you mean by "out of scope". It is simply a boolean I declared globally for the purpose of having two different possible JSONDownloads (one of which has been [REDACTED] to save space on Stack Overflow) without needing two different classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't overriding the correct method for [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

You have:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
```

You need:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
```

Notice the third generic parameter you supplied was of type `Object`. That's the type that `onPostExecute` uses as an argument. So, the method signature for `onPostExecute` needs to accept an `Object`, not `Void`.

You should probably use a result type of boolean here rather than object, and remove the Json state class variable. This keeps your AsyncTask more flexible, and could allow you to display some indication the operation completed to the user after execution.

Comment: nice didn't see that. But it would be good if you'd mention that - in his case - the return type `Object` makes no sense anyway and he should change it (either to void or even better to boolean and remove the class variable JSONstate) :)

Comment: GG. typical case of failure to use @Override annotation.

Comment: I'm confused, will using Object or not work?

Further clarification on what's wrong with me using a Global boolean to perform one of two different JSON Downloads depending on which method requested the downloader.

Comment: Using object will work. It isn't a problem that you're using a classwide variable except that its unnecessary. The result of your operation in `doInBackground` will be passed to `onPostExecute`, so why store it classwide if you'll have access to it anyway in `onPosteExecute`?

Comment: Thank you, the code does now function. Why I use the class wide variable I dunno, I just kinda through this together in a hurry for a test and stuck with it since. Thanks for the suggestion, I may filter it out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say you codes in AsyncTask is nothing matches the point.

AsyncTask is designed as another thread running out from the UI-thread. So you should either use it as a inner class which is in a running UI-thread, then the onPostExecute() part can do something to show the result, or you as your codes, if you leave it as a stand alone class. You should design an interface, other class, like activity or fragment, which run new AsyncTask.execute() should implements that interface.

Also, java is not javascript. Your variables in doInBackground() is only limited in the function. So what you did in onPostExecute() will get nothing.

You should either use

```
JSONObject jsonOrg
```

as a class variable or you should return that at the end of doInBackground() and gain it back in onPostExecute()

After all, I suggest you look at the api document's example. Although it is a little complex, but it shows everything perfect.

Answer (score -1):

try to use override methods

```
               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    Log.i("in on ", "entered");
                    hideProgress();
                   }
```

As suggested by william the type should match with the override methods. I have edited the answer below

```
          public class JSONDownloader extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                   }
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of your code within the onPostExecute method?

Comment: @Margaret dont look up the code within onPostExecute method, its just to verify the logcat wether the code is reached and we can use hideprogress() if u set progressbar

Comment: @WilliamMorrison why so?

Comment: @Margaret cheers it works na :) try to accept the answer or upvote it

Comment: Because the type of `result` is *not* `Void`, its `Object` as declared  in his `JSONDownloader` class definition. This will not work without changing the type when extending AsyncTask.